# Error installing nuget package Swashbuckle

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, swagger

I'm trying to install nuget package `Swashbuckle` to a new project that will get me swagger things. I created the project and then tried to add project but I'm getting the error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1107  Version conflict detected for Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client. Install/reference Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.6 directly to project TestAPI to resolve this issue. 
 TestAPI -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1 -> Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client (>= 5.2.6 && < 5.3.0) 
 TestAPI -> Swashbuckle 5.6.0 -> Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost 4.0.20710 -> Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 4.0.20710 -> Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client (>= 4.0.20710 && < 4.1.0).   TestAPI
```

How do I resolve this error? I have upgraded all packages and things I could find...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
PM> Install-Package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore --version 4.0.1
```

Reference : [Get started with Swashbuckle and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#package-installation)

Comment: Wondering why I am not able to install higher or latest version of Swashbuckle with Aspnet Core 2.2.x We still have error of version conflict